# libxmu.so.6 cannot open shared object file

Tags: software-installation

I am tried to install a program but it gave me this text
TclError: couldn't load file "/home/rafael/MGLTools-1.5.6/MGLToolsPckgs/opengltk/OpenGL/Tk/Togl/togl.so": libXmu.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
What can i do?

Comment: Is the `libxmu6` package installed?

Comment: Yes it is installed

Comment: mgltools_i86Linux2_1.5.6.tar.gz is **32bits**. You'd probably want the 64bits version → `mgltools_x86_64Linux2_1.5.6.tar.gz`  http://mgltools.scripps.edu/downloads

Comment: That was really useful. It solve completely problem thanks